# Realizar un query de la manera mas rápida posible vb.net en MYSql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hola que tal? tengo una clase para realizar las consultas de manera ágil posible, en un principio me resultaba rápida pero ahora que tengo consultas muy complejas me resulta lento.

Quisiera saber cómo puedo reducir los tiempos de ejecución, a continuación la clase y la consulta  que realizo, la consulta en si se realiza de manera rápida, con sus indices y una formulacion sencilla, el problema es el manejo de datos y la comunicación con la base de datos en vb.net, por separado pude verificar los tiempos y el resultado es mejor en mysql, la consulta corre 300 milisegundos mientras en vb.net tarda 3 segundos.

En el programa al realizar muchas consultas me resulta muy lento y bastante tedioso, quisiera saber si alguien que sabe del tema puede encontrar una mejor o ve una forma mas rapida de realizar la consulta a travez de VB.NET
La base de datos la manejo en Mariadb. A continuacion la declaracion de las tablas:

**Tabla Contabilidad:** en esta tabla se guardan los movimientos contables, por ejemplo pagos

```
CREATE TABLE `contabilidad` (
    `anulado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `cuentacorriente` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `cuotas` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    `empleado` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    `formadepago` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `idgasto` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `interesfinanciero` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    `interesformadepago` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    `ticketid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `tipodetransaccion` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `transaccion` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    `valordecuota` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    `valorfinal` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `fecha` (`fecha`),
    INDEX `ticketid` (`ticketid`),
    INDEX `idgasto` (`idgasto`),
    INDEX `formadepago` (`formadepago`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `tipodetransaccion` (`tipodetransaccion`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=47
;
```

**Tabla ticket:** en esta tabla se guardan las ventas realizadas, por ejemplo una venta de 5 productos

```
CREATE TABLE `tickets` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    `anulacion` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `total` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    `descuento` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    `cuentacorriente` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `empleado` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `terminal` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `senacliente` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `devolucion` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    `formasdepago` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `señacliente` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`),
    INDEX `anulacion` (`anulacion`),
    INDEX `fecha` (`fecha`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=38
;
```

**Tablas ticket productos:** Aqui se detallan la venta realizada, referente a tickets, tabla anterior

```
CREATE TABLE `ticketproductos` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `notadecreditoid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `idrubro` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `precio2` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    `ticketid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `productoid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `cantidad` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    `precio` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    `porpeso` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `anulado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `promocionid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `preciooriginal` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    `pesodeprecio` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1.00,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id_2` (`id`),
    INDEX `id` (`id`),
    INDEX `idrubro` (`idrubro`),
    INDEX `ticketid` (`ticketid`),
    INDEX `productoid` (`productoid`),
    INDEX `anulado` (`anulado`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

**Tabla Productos:** Aquí se detallan los productos:

```
CREATE TABLE `productos` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `categoria` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `balanzaid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `proveedor` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `cantidad` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    `stockminimo` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 4.00,
    `fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
    `eliminado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `especial` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `ingresosbrutos` DECIMAL(3,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    `tipodeproducto` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `cantidadbultocerrado` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    `cantidadbultoabierto` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    `ultimamodificacion` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`),
    INDEX `eliminado` (`eliminado`),
    INDEX `ultimamodificacion` (`ultimamodificacion`),
    INDEX `id2` (`id`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `nombre` (`nombre`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `nombre_2` (`nombre`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=6416
;
```

*A continuacion el codigo de VB.NET:*

Declaracion de tabla :

```
Using tabla As New DataTable
                With tabla
                    .formatear("Pagos")
                    .agregarcoldec("Pago")
                    .agregarcolstr("Medio de Pago")
                    .agregarcoldec("Valor Total")
                    .agregarcoldec("Valor cuota")
                    .agregarcolint("Cuotas")
                    .agregarcoldec("interesformadepago")
                    .agregarcoldec("interesfinanciero")
                    .agregarcolint("formadepago")
                    .agregarcolint("cuentacorriente")
                End With
                contabilidaddatos.Tables.Add(tabla)
Using tabla As New DataTable
                With tabla
                    .formatear("Datosdeticket")
                    .agregarcoldec("total con financiacion")
                    .agregarcoldec("cantidad de articulos")
                    .agregarcolstr("consulta nombre")
                    .agregarcoldec("consulta cantidad")
                    .agregarcoldec("consulta precio")
                    .agregarcoldec("devolucion")
                    .agregarcoldec("paga con")
                    .agregarcoldec("subtotal")
                    .agregarcolstr("nombre de ultimo producto")
                    .Rows.Add()
                End With
                contabilidaddatos.Tables.Add(tabla)
Using tabla As New DataTable
                tabla.formatear("DetallesFinanciacion")
                contabilidaddatos.Tables.Add(tabla)
            End Using
Using tabla As New DataTable
                With tabla
                    .formatear("Pagos")
                    .agregarcoldec("Pago")
                    .agregarcolstr("Medio de Pago")
                    .agregarcoldec("Valor Total")
                    .agregarcoldec("Valor cuota")
                    .agregarcolint("Cuotas")
                    .agregarcoldec("interesformadepago")
                    .agregarcoldec("interesfinanciero")
                    .agregarcolint("formadepago")
                    .agregarcolint("cuentacorriente")
                End With
                contabilidaddatos.Tables.Add(tabla)
```

Aquí se declara la tabla con funciones propias, *formatear* le da nombre, y las *agregarcol* Agrega columnas y dependiendo de su final es el tipo de columna por ejemplo *agregarcoldec* agrega una columna de tipo decimal.
A continuacion a funcion **"Cerrar venta"**

```
Dim idticket As Integer
        Using comu As New mysqlcustom
            If contabilidaddatos.Tables("Ticket").Rows.Count = 0 Then Return -1
            'Dim tiempoprueba As Decimal = (Date.Now - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds
            Dim devolucion As Decimal
            If contabilidaddatos.Tables("Pagos").Rows.Count = 0 Then
                If pagadocon < total Then pagadocon = total
                If pagadocon > total Then
                    devolucion = total - pagadocon
                    pagadocon = total
                End If
                agregarpago(pagadocon)
            End If
            contabilidaddatos.Tables("Datosdeticket").Rows(0).Item("paga con") = pagadocon
            contabilidaddatos.Tables("Datosdeticket").Rows(0).Item("devolucion") = devolucion
            comu.agregarquery("INSERT INTO tickets (id, fecha) VALUES (NULL, DEFAULT);SET @ticketid := LAST_INSERT_ID();")           
            Dim primero As Boolean = True
            Dim sql As String
            sql = "INSERT INTO ticketproductos (ticketid,notadecreditoid, idrubro, precio, cantidad, porpeso, promocionid, preciooriginal, productoid, pesodeprecio" & If(intercomunicacion.Pespeciales, ", precio2", "") & ") VALUES"
            Dim campo As Integer
            For Each row As DataRow In contabilidaddatos.Tables("Ticket").Rows
                campo += 1
                If primero Then
                    primero = False
                Else
                    sql &= ","
                End If
                comu.agregarparametromasivo("?notadecreditoid" & campo, CInt(row.Item("notadecreditoid")))
                comu.agregarparametromasivo("?idrubro" & campo, CInt(row.Item("idrubro")))
                comu.agregarparametromasivo("?precio" & campo, CDec(row.Item("Precio")))
                comu.agregarparametromasivo("?cantidad" & campo, CDec(row.Item("cantidad")))
                comu.agregarparametromasivo("?porpeso" & campo, CInt(row.Item("porpeso")))
                comu.agregarparametromasivo("?promocionid" & campo, CInt(row.Item("promocionid")))
                comu.agregarparametromasivo("?preciooriginal" & campo, CDec(row.Item("preciooriginal")))
                comu.agregarparametromasivo("?productoid" & campo, CInt(row.Item("productoid")))
                comu.agregarparametromasivo("?pesodeprecio" & campo, CDec(row.Item("pesodeprecio")))
                If intercomunicacion.Pespeciales Then comu.agregarparametromasivo("?precioespecial" & campo, CDec(row.Item("preciodefraccion")))
                sql &= " (@ticketid, ?notadecreditoid" & campo & ", ?idrubro" & campo & ", ?precio" & campo & ", ?cantidad" & campo & ", ?porpeso" & campo & ", ?promocionid" & campo & ", ?preciooriginal" & campo & ", ?productoid" & campo & ", ?pesodeprecio" & campo & If(intercomunicacion.Pespeciales, ", ?precioespecial" & campo, "") & ")"
            Next
            sql &= ";"           
            comu.agregarquery(sql)
            For Each row As DataRow In contabilidaddatos.Tables("Ticket").Rows
                If row.Item("productoid") <> 0 Then
                    If row.Item("porpeso") = 1 Then
                        comu.agregarparametromasivo("?cantidad", CDec(row.Item("Cantidad")))
                        comu.agregarparametromasivo("?productoid", CInt(row.Item("productoid")))
                        comu.agregarquery("UPDATE productos SET cantidad = cantidad - ( ?cantidad DIV cantidadbultocerrado), cantidadbultoabierto =  cantidadbultoabierto - MOD( ?cantidad, cantidadbultocerrado) WHERE id = ?productoid ; UPDATE productos SET cantidad = IF (cantidadbultoabierto<0, cantidad -1,cantidad), cantidadbultoabierto = IF (cantidadbultoabierto<0, cantidadbultocerrado + cantidadbultoabierto, cantidadbultoabierto) WHERE id = ?productoid;")
                    Else
                        comu.agregarparametromasivo("?cantidad", CDec(row.Item("Cantidad")))
                        comu.agregarparametromasivo("?productoid", CInt(row.Item("productoid")))
                        comu.agregarquery("UPDATE productos SET cantidad = cantidad - ?cantidad WHERE id = ?productoid ;")
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            'cierra ticket
            Dim cuotas As Integer = 0
            Dim interes As Decimal = 0
            With contabilidaddatos.Tables("DetallesFinanciacion")
                If .Select("id=" & financiacionseleccionada).Length > 0 Then
                    interes = CDec(.Select("id=" & financiacionseleccionada)(0).Item("Interes"))
                    cuotas = CInt(.Select("id=" & financiacionseleccionada)(0).Item("Cuotas"))
                End If
            End With
            comu.agregarparametromasivo("?total", total)
            comu.agregarparametromasivo("?devolucion", devolucion)
            comu.agregarquery("UPDATE tickets SET anulacion = 0, devolucion = ?devolucion, total = ?total, cuentacorriente = 0 WHERE id = @ticketid;")
            sql = ""
            campo = 0
            With contabilidaddatos.Tables("Pagos")
                campo += 1
                If .Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    sql &= "INSERT INTO contabilidad (ticketid, cuentacorriente, empleado, fecha, interesfinanciero, interesformadepago, cuotas, transaccion, tipodetransaccion, formadepago, valordecuota, valorfinal) VALUES "
                    primero = True
                    'comu.agregarparametromasivo("?usuariologueado", usuariologueado)
                    For Each row As DataRow In .Rows
                        If primero Then
                            primero = False
                        Else
                            sql &= ","
                        End If
                        comu.agregarparametromasivo("?interesfinanciero" & campo, CDec(row.Item("interesfinanciero")))
                        comu.agregarparametromasivo("?interesformadepago" & campo, CDec(row.Item("interesformadepago")))
                        comu.agregarparametromasivo("?formadepago" & campo, CInt(row.Item("formadepago")))
                        comu.agregarparametromasivo("?cuotas" & campo, CInt(row.Item("Cuotas")))
                        comu.agregarparametromasivo("?pago" & campo, CDec(row.Item("Pago")))
                        comu.agregarparametromasivo("?valortotal" & campo, CDec(row.Item("Valor Total")))
                        comu.agregarparametromasivo("?valorcuota" & campo, CDec(row.Item("Valor cuota")))
                        sql &= "(@ticketid, 0, OBTENEREMPLEADO(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?interesfinanciero" & campo & ", ?interesformadepago" & campo & ", ?cuotas" & campo & ", ?pago" & campo & ", 'pago', ?formadepago" & campo & ",?valortotal" & campo & ",?valorcuota" & campo & ")"
                    Next
                    sql &= ";"
                    comu.agregarquery(sql)
                End If
            End With
            comu.agregarquery(estadosistemasql("iniciado"))
            comu.agregarqueryconsulta("SELECT @ticketid")     
                idticket = comu.ejecutarquerymasivo()
                If comu.ultimatransaccionsatisfactoria Then
                    'comunicacion.finalizartransaccion()
                    mensaje("Venta realizada con éxito")
                Else
                    mensaje("No se pudo realizar la venta!", True)
                End If           
            End If
        End Using
        Return idticket
```

Esta funcion cierra una venta almacenada en el dataset declarado anteriormente, A continuacion la clase Mysqlcustom, la que utilizo para comunicar el programa con la base de datos.
A continuacion la declaracion de la clase parametros para realizar las consultas

```
Public Class parametro
    Public Shared NextID As Integer = 0
    Public ID As Integer
    Public Property columnadestino As String = ""
    Public Property tabla As String = ""
    Public Property columnaid As Integer = 0
    Public Property nombre As String
    Public Sub New()
        ID = NextID
        NextID += 1
    End Sub
```

Y a continuacion la clase que utilizo para comunicar el programa con la base de datos, **mysqlcustom**

```
Public Class mysqlcustom
    Private ultimoquerymasivo As String = ""
     Public ultimatransaccionsatisfactoria As Boolean 'es para informar que la transferencia se realizo satisfactoriamente
    private parametroslista As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Object, parametro))
    Private sql As New DataTable
    sub new ()
        Private sql As New DataTable  With sql
                If .Columns.Count = 0 Then
                    .agregarcolstr("SQL")
                    .agregarcolint("id", True)
                End If
        End With            
    end sub
    Sub agregarqueryconsulta(sql As String)' aqui se declara la ultima consulta sql para regresar una respuesta en la funcion ejecutarquerymasivo
        ultimoquerymasivo = sql
    End Sub
    Public Sub agregarparametromasivo(nombre As String, objeto As Object) 'aqui se guardan los parametros a parametroslista para el query en ejecutarquerymasivo
        If nombre = "" Then Exit Sub
        Dim nuevoitem = New KeyValuePair(Of Object, parametro)(objeto, New parametro With {.columnaid = ultimoidsqlmasivo(), .nombre = nombre})
        parametroslista.Add(nuevoitem)
    End Sub
    public Sub agregarquery(sqll As String)
        If sql.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            sql.Rows.Add(sqll, 1)
        Else
            sql.Rows.Add(sqll)
        End If
    End Sub
    Function ejecutarquerymasivo() As Object
        Dim respuesta As New Object
        If sql.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Using conexion As New MySqlConnection(conexionstring)
reintentar:
                Try
                    conexion.Open()'iniciar conexion mysql
                Catch ex As Exception
                    configurarsistema(ex.Message, ex.HelpLink, ex.StackTrace)' esta funcion es para configurar la base datos, es irrelevante
                    GoTo reintentar
                End Try                   
                    ultimatransaccionsatisfactoria = False                    
                    Dim transaccionmysql As MySqlTransaction
                    transaccionmysql = conexion.BeginTransaction
                    Try
                        For Each consulta As DataRow In sql.Rows
                            Using query2 As New MySqlCommand(consulta.Item("sql").ToString, conexion)
                                query2.Transaction = transaccionmysql
                                For Each parametross As KeyValuePair(Of Object, parametro) In parametroslista.Where(Function(kvp) kvp.Value.columnaid = CInt(consulta("id"))) '.Select(Function(kvp) kvp.Key)
                                    query2.Parameters.AddWithValue(parametross.Value.nombre, parametross.Key)
                                Next
                                If consulta.Item("sql").ToString <> "" Then
                                    If logbasededatos Then log("Comando:" & query2.CommandText,, "query")
                                    query2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                                End If
                                query2.Dispose()
                            End Using
                        Next
                        If Not ultimoquerymasivo.Equals("") Then ' se verifica si hay una ultima consulta para realizar una ultima respuesta 
                            Using query As New MySqlCommand(ultimoquerymasivo, conexion)
                                query.Transaction = transaccionmysql
                                Using sqlreader As MySqlDataReader = query.ExecuteReader
                                    If sqlreader.Read() Then
                                        respuesta = sqlreader(0)
                                    End If
                                    query.Dispose()
                                End Using
                            End Using
                        End If
                        transaccionmysql.Commit()
                        transaccionmysql.Dispose()
                        ultimatransaccionsatisfactoria = True
                        If logbasededatos Then log("Se ejecuta el query masivo con transaccion satisfactoriamente...",, "query")
                    Catch e As Exception
                        If logbasededatos Then log("No se pudo ejecutar el query masivo con transaccion satisfactoriamente...",, "query")                        
                        MsgBox("Ultima transaccion u operación fue anulada, por favor intente realizarla nuevamente", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error Crítico")
                    Finally
                        conexion.Close()
                    End Try                
        Return respuesta
    End Function
    end class
```

Esta realiza toda la consulta realizada en la funcion anterior. como dije anteriormente en una venta de al menos 30 productos, en la consulta mysql tarda 1 segundo, mientras que las funcines "agregarparametromasivo" y "agregarconsulta" son muy lentas, tarda 3 segundos, no deberia ser tanto, creo yo, Tal vez keyvaluepair es un metodo lento para realizar movimientos de datos masivos?
La clase mysqlcustom es general para toda la solución y tiene muchas partes que es utilizada, lo que me interesa es está clase, en como mejorar la performance, puede que el problema sea keyvaluepair, la manera de llevar los parámetros, hay alguna manera más rápida? Teniendo en cuenta que con keyvaluepair puedo llevar objetos, y esos no necesitan ser identificador porque el procedimiento parámetros.addvalue no necesita especificar, puede ser date, boolean, string o binary y este lo tomara correctamente. Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Esta es una pregunta interesante.. creo que tus clases antes de generar la consulta hacen demasiadas cosas.. muchas de ellas, que parecen son para ahorrar codigo, solo generan mas codigo al final. Podrias tratar de dejar solo las partes que generan las consultas asi revisamos eso? por ejemplo pasas por un lado el query, por otro los parametros, y despues otra funcion trata de unir todo con las perdidas de tiempo que ves.

Comment: Me podrías decir exactamente a qué parte del código crees que está demás? Con respecto a la consulta, está bien, el problema es el manejo de las variables, quisiera saber cono hacer me rápido eso

Comment: En mi opinion, y no es mala la pregunta lo vuelvo a aclararlo.. la defincion de las tablas no importa, asi como tampoco la clase que esta llena de datatables.. aunque un datatable es una estructura pesada, y tal vez solo necesites tener una lista para evitar todo el overhead. La parte interesante es ver como pides un query (cualquiera, y con parametros) y por donde pasa eso, que es lo que tarda tiempo...

Comment: La clase mysqlcustom es general para toda la solución y tiene muchas partes que es utilizada, lo que me interesa es está clase, es como mejorar la performance, puede que el problema sea keyvaluepair, la manera de llevar los parámetros, hay alguna manera más rápida? Teniendo en cuenta que con keyvaluepair puedo llevar objetos, y esos no necesitan ser identificador porque el procedimiento parámetros.addvalue no necesita especificar, puede ser date, boolean, string o binary y este lo tomara correctamente, por esa razon pero parece que es el problema, no lo sé